# Genericity of semisimplicity

Tags: representation-theory

In his [survey on the Jones polynomial](https://math.berkeley.edu/~vfr/jonesakl.pdf), Vaughan Jones says that

> Semisimplicity is a "generic" condition- it is true whenever the "Killing form" is non-singular so for an algebra depending on a parameter like $TL$, it will be semisimple for all but a finite number of values of $\tau$ provided it is semisimple for a single value.

I would like to know what exactly is the "Killing form" he is referring to, since $TL$ is not a Lie algebra but an associative one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$, for any $a \in A$ we can consider the left multiplication operator $L_a : A \to A$. This lets us define the trace

$$\text{tr}(a) = \text{tr}(L_a) : A \to k$$

and hence the trace form

$$\text{tr}(ab) = \text{tr}(L_a L_b) : A \otimes A \to k.$$

"Killing form" is in quotes because the construction here is closely analogous to the construction of the Killing form. Possibly under some hypotheses I can't remember off the top of my head, if the trace form is nondegenerate then $A$ is semisimple.

Comment: Thanks @Qiaochu! Indeed, this is the case. I add some more details for completeness' sake. Let $I$ be a minimal bilateral ideal of $A$. From basic properties of the trace it can be seen that the orthogonal complement $I^\perp$ it is also a bilateral ideal. Now $A=I\oplus I^\perp$ by non-degeneracy, and so $1=e+f$ with $e\in I$ and $f\in I^\perp$. One can check that both $I$ and $I^\perp$ are unital algebras, with unit $e$ and $f$ respectively. It is easy to check that $I$ is simple, since it is a minimal ideal of $A$, ...

Comment: ...and since the restriction of the trace form to $I^\perp$ is non-degenerate as well, we may suppose $I^\perp$ is semisimple by induction on the dimension, which completes the proof.

Comment: (No other hypotheses besides finite-dimensionality and the non-degeneracy of the trace form are needed).

Comment: I think the hypotheses I had in mind are about the converse (that is, whether semisimplicity implies the trace form is nondegenerate).

Comment: One needs the characteristic of the ground field to be zero for the converse to hold. Once again thanks a lot!